# Stop intensive file process?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following function to read files into a spreadsheet.  I was thinking of adding a stop button ([something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979893/how-to-stop-vba-code-running)) but the problem is that while this is running it completely locks up Excel and I cannot interact with it in any way.  Is there a way to gracefully stop something like this?  Note that these are huge files (500,000+ lines)

```
Function LoadFile(m)
        Dim WrdArray() As String
        Dim txtstrm As TextStream
        Dim line As String
        Dim clm As Long
        Dim Rw As Long
        Dim Dash As Worksheet
        Set Dash = Sheets("Dashboard")
        Set cellStatus = Dash.Range("E3")
        Set txtstrm = FSO.OpenTextFile("s:\views_" & m & ".txt")
        Rw = 1
        Do Until txtstrm.AtEndOfStream
          If Rw Mod 4 = 0 Then cellStatus.Value = "Loading " & m & "... /"
          If Rw Mod 4 = 1 Then cellStatus.Value = "Loading " & m & "... |"
          If Rw Mod 4 = 2 Then cellStatus.Value = "Loading " & m & "... \"
          If Rw Mod 4 = 3 Then cellStatus.Value = "Loading " & m & "... -"
          line = txtstrm.ReadLine
          clm = 1
          WrdArray() = Split(line, "|!|")
          For Each wrd In WrdArray()
            Sheets(m).Cells(Rw, clm) = wrd
            clm = clm + 1
          Next wrd
          Rw = Rw + 1
        Loop
        txtstrm.Close
        LoadFile = Rw
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but adding DoEvents to each cycle might enable user input to be interpreted. Then ctrl+break will work, but remember to add error handling. Or you can try listening to keypresses after the DoEvents command. I sadly can't test it now, but might worth looking into.

Comment: Why not use `Application.StatusBar = "Loading " & m` instead of changing a cell value? Remember to `Application.StatusBar = False` at end of sub to reset it.

Comment: Another idea is to read to whole file (`txtstrm.ReadAll`), have another Variant to store the Split with `vbCrLf` instead of line by line. But with that much lines, I am not sure if that is ok with Excel.

Answer (score 1):

First, turn off screen refreshing and calculation.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

then at the very end, turn back on

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = XlCalculationAutomatic
```

Additonally, if you add some type of counter that, after X iterations, prompts the user to continue or not, something like

```
Dim myCount as Long
...your loop starts here
myCount = myCount + 1
If myCount mod 1000 = 0 then
     toContinue = msgBox("Continue with macro?",vbYesNo)
     If toContinue = vbNo then exit sub
End if
...continue loop
```

Edit: Bah, I'll have to tweak that `If myCount mod 1000 = 0` to something better...basically an even divisor of 1000 or something.

Also, is the loading "animation" required? I bet that contributes to it taking long when running over that many cells. And, just thought of it, when you turn off screenupdating, you *won't* see that animation, so maybe comment it out and see how it runs.

Comment: The animation isn't required but it's nice to know *something* is happening.  I will test without it though... after it runs this time :)

Comment: @ScottBeeson - I haven't used it a lot, but it might be quicker for Excel if you instead update the status via the `StatusBar`, i.e. `Application.StatusBar = "Running part 1"`  then later you can change the text to "part 2" or whatever, so you know it's working.

Answer (score 1):

In order for excel not to 'lock up' you have to call 'DoEvents'. Using the following will also speed up your process, however it appears as though you'll need screen updating to update the status bar, and EnableEvents to operate your button press event.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

You can use the application's status bar at the very bottom if you want by doing the following:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Your Value Here"
```

Just make sure to clear it before you leave your function. If you wanted to be really 'safe' you can store its old previous value before writing to it then restore it here.

```
Application.StatusBar = ""
```

Your modified code is below:

```
Function LoadFile(m)
    Dim WrdArray() As String
    Dim txtstrm As TextStream
    Dim line As String
    Dim clm As Long
    Dim Rw As Long
    Dim Dash As Worksheet

    Application.Calculation = xlManual   

    Set Dash = Sheets("Dashboard")
    Set cellStatus = Dash.Range("E3")

    Set txtstrm = FSO.OpenTextFile("s:\views_" & m & ".txt")

    Rw = 1
    Do Until txtstrm.AtEndOfStream
      If Rw Mod 4 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = "Loading " & m & "... /"
      If Rw Mod 4 = 1 Then Application.StatusBar = "Loading " & m & "... |"
      If Rw Mod 4 = 2 Then Application.StatusBar = "Loading " & m & "... \"
      If Rw Mod 4 = 3 Then Application.StatusBar = "Loading " & m & "... -"
      line = txtstrm.ReadLine
      clm = 1
      WrdArray() = Split(line, "|!|")
      For Each wrd In WrdArray()
        Sheets(m).Cells(Rw, clm) = wrd
        clm = clm + 1
      Next wrd
      Rw = Rw + 1
      'This will insure that excel doesn't lock up or freeze
      DoEvents
    Loop
    txtstrm.Close
    LoadFile = Rw

    Application.Calculation = XlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Function
```

Comment: I don't know that he needs `DoEvents`, but otherwise, I like your tips. :P

Comment: He is asking if there is a way to gracefully stop it with a Macro button. If Excel locks up, you cannot use the macro button to force the stop. Using a forced dialog every 1k rows isn't very optimal. Maybe call 'DoEvents' every 500 rows or so would be optimal, instead of calling it every iteration.

Comment: @BruceWayne `DoEvents` returns control from the executing program to the processor in order to process any pending commands (such as worksheet _events_ \* wink wink \* ) - To halt execution in looped code something like this is essential.

Comment: Interesting, so I should probably not disable events then, since it will disable direct events as well... interesting. For some reason I was thinking click events weren't affected, but that was a misnomer on my case.

Comment: @KrisB Don't want to get off-topic here - but basically you can disable events, and then use `DoEvents` to manually "fire" any events that may be pending. This is particularly useful for preventing infinite loops when using a change event for example.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you do this in a Function, but if you have Sub that calls this, it may be better to pause calculation there.

Anyway, try this (dumping array values in one go):

```
Function LoadFile(m)
    Dim WrdArray() As String
    Dim txtstrm As Object
    Dim line As String
    Dim clm As Long ' Now used as number of items in the Split
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim Rw As Long
    Dim Dash As Worksheet

    Set Dash = Sheets("Dashboard")
    'Set cellStatus = Dash.Range("E3")
    Set txtstrm = FSO.OpenTextFile("s:\views_" & m & ".txt")

    Rw = 1
    CalcMode = Application.Calculation ' Save calculation mode
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual ' Change to Manual Calculation
    Do Until txtstrm.AtEndOfStream
        Application.StatusBar = Now & ": Loading " & m & " (Rw: " & Rw & ")"
        'If Rw Mod 4 = 0 Then cellStatus.Value = "Loading " & m & "... /"
        'If Rw Mod 4 = 1 Then cellStatus.Value = "Loading " & m & "... |"
        'If Rw Mod 4 = 2 Then cellStatus.Value = "Loading " & m & "... \"
        'If Rw Mod 4 = 3 Then cellStatus.Value = "Loading " & m & "... -"
        line = txtstrm.ReadLine
        'clm = 1
        WrdArray = Split(line, "|!|")
        clm = UBound(WrdArray) + 1 ' Number of items in the split
        ' Dump the array to cells value to resized range from Col A
        Sheets(m).Cells(Rw, "A").Resize(, clm).Value = WrdArray
        'For Each wrd In WrdArray()
        '    Sheets(m).Cells(Rw, clm) = wrd
        '    clm = clm + 1
        'Next wrd
        Rw = Rw + 1
    Loop
    txtstrm.Close
    Application.StatusBar = False ' Reset status bar
    Application.Calculation = CalcMode ' restore calculation mode
    LoadFile = Rw
End Function
```

Comment: I'm only doing it in a function so I can return the total number of rows added.  I guess I could do this another way but is there a reason I shouldn't use a function?

Comment: Function without Private can be called within a Cell. If you only use this within Subs in same Module, then should use `Private Function`.

Comment: Is there a disadvantage to not privatizing it?

Comment: If a Function is not Private, it's available as an Excel Function, which needs more error handling codes to prevent misuse. Imagine a user filled tens of cells with `=LoadFile("Test")`, it would consume Excel dramatically. Making it Private will prevent that.