# VBA Application or object defined error when ending a sub

Tags: vba, excel

So I've set up a custom ribbon that has two buttons: one for running a simulation, and another for cancelling it. When the simulation macro is running, a progress bar appears until it has finished.

The cancel button runs a sub that just has `End`. But the issue is that when the user clicks cancel, an error comes up that says "Application defined or object defined error"

Basically I'm trying to get a button in the ribbon that stops the simulation macro without throwing an error.

I've tried using an `On Error` statement to go to the end of the sub, but it still comes up the same. Here is the code for the macro:

```
Public Sub SimCallback(control As IRibbonControl)

Dim CurrentTrial As Long
Dim NumberOfTrials As Long
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim EndTime As Double
Dim SimBar As ProgressBar
Set SimBar = New ProgressBar

' Custom parameters for progress bar. References separate class
With SimBar
    .Title = "Simulation Progress"
    .StartColour = rgbGreen
    .Top = Application.Top + 125
    .Left = Application.Left + 25
End With

' Pre-sim actions
Worksheets("Histograms").EnableCalculation = False
Worksheets("Monte Carlo Results").EnableCalculation = False
StartTime = Timer
Worksheets("Monte Carlo Calculation").Range("U1:V10000").Clear
Let CurrentTrial = 1
NumberOfTrials = Worksheets("Monte Carlo Results").Range("M2").value
SimBar.TotalActions = NumberOfTrials
SimBar.ShowBar

' Loop repeats until selected number of trials have been performed.
' Values are stored in U and V columns on same sheet.

Do While CurrentTrial < NumberOfTrials
    DoEvents
    Worksheets("Monte Carlo Calculation").Calculate
    For CurrentTrial = 1 To NumberOfTrials
        Worksheets("Monte Carlo Calculation").Range("U" & CurrentTrial).value = Worksheets("Monte Carlo Calculation").Range("J2").value
        Worksheets("Monte Carlo Calculation").Range("V" & CurrentTrial).value = Worksheets("Monte Carlo Calculation").Range("T2").value
        SimBar.NextAction
        Next CurrentTrial
    CurrentTrial = CurrentTrial + 1
Loop

' Output range is copied to separate sheet, since referencing the original sheet slowed down the simulation time.

Worksheets("Monte Carlo Calculation").Range("U1:V10000").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Histograms").Range("H1:J10000")
Worksheets("Histograms").EnableCalculation = True
Worksheets("Monte Carlo Results").EnableCalculation = True

' Display sim time and terminate progress bar
EndTime = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
SimBar.Terminate
MsgBox "Simulation Complete (" & EndTime & " seconds)", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979893/how-to-stop-vba-code-running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On possibility is as follows:

1) Create a public variable called e.g. `Running`:

```
Public Running As Boolean
```

declared in a standard code module outside of any procedure.

2) In the code for `SimCallback`, have the line

```
Running = True
```

towards the top of the code and replace

```
Do While CurrentTrial < NumberOfTrials
```

by

```
Do While Running And CurrentTrial < NumberOfTrials
```

3) In the code for the cancel button, replace `End` by

```
Running = False
```

This will allow the cleanup line `SimBar.Terminate` to execute.