# Using a variable in 2 subs

Tags: excel, variables, userform

I have over 20 subs in an excel file, and some userforms. In one userform, there is a cancel button, but I cannot use the "if cancel = true" kinda code in another sub. I don't know why, but it never comes true. So I thought that if I can state a variable to be true in userform, then check that variable in another sub, then that may work but unfortunately I couldn't figure that either. In below you can find both codes;

This is userform;

```
Private Sub Sheet_Iptal_Click()
Dim Sheet_Iptal As String
Sheet_Iptal = True
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Storyboard").Delete
Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Hide
MsgBox "Islem iptal edildi."
Yeni_Sheet_Adi_Olustur.Yeni_Sheet.Value = ""
End Sub
```

And here is the part of the other sub where I want to check that "Sheet_Iptal" situation;

```
If Sheet_Iptal = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Storyboard").Delete
    GoTo son
End If
```

What I am basically trying to achieve in here is, if cancel button has been used, then go to "son" of that specific sub.
I am open to any suggestions here.

Comment: something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979893/how-to-stop-vba-code-running?

Comment: But the value of the variable gets emptied when userform ends. I doesn't carry it's value to the main sub. That's the main problem for me right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UserForm `.Tag` property can be set to something on the button click events:

```
Private Sub buttonOK_Click()
    Me.Tag = "OK"
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub buttonCancel_Click()
    Me.Tag = "Cancel"
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

and then check it's value after showing the form:

```
UserForm1.Show
MsgBox UserForm1.Tag <> "OK"
```