# How to temporarily stop event script on incoming emails?

Tags: vba, outlook, procedure

I process incoming emails with

```
Private WithEvents objNewMailItems As Outlook.Items
```

as startup procedure and

```
Private Sub objNewMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
```

executing whenever a new email arrives in the inbox.

How can I (manually) stop this procedure from executing?

Comment: `Set objNewMailItems = Nothing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`objNewMailItems` is declared as an event provider; as long as its reference is set, it will fire events.

To make it stop, you need to set its reference to `Nothing`.

```
Public Sub StopHandlingNewMailItems()
    Set objNewMailItems = Nothing
End Sub
```

Take the code you have that's currently assigning that object reference, move it to some `StartHandlingNewMailItems()` procedure, and invoke it at startup; now you can toggle handling new mail items on/off at will.

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemAdd` event may not be fired at all if multiple items (more than sixteen) are added to the folder. I'd recommend handling the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class instead. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

```
Private Sub outApp_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    if Cancel then
      Dim itm as Outlook.MailItem
      Set itm = NS.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection)

      If itm.Class = olMail Then

        Debug.Print "mail received"
        Debug.Print itm.Parent.Parent.name

      End If
    End If
End Sub
```

To prevent the VBA macro from running you can add a button called "CancelButton" that sets a flag, and then check for that flag in the `NewMailEx` event handler.

```
Bool Cancel
Private Sub CancelButton_OnClick()
    Cancel=True
End Sub
```

Finally, you may find the [How to stop VBA code running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979893/how-to-stop-vba-code-running) post helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. Ill accept the other one though, as it is more streamlined to my case.